# Amazon S3 Glacier vs Glacier Storage Class

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

This question might look like an easy/idiot/beginner question but I'm really confused between both of them.

Why do I need to use **Amazon S3 Glacier** if I can use the normal **S3 Bucket** and just change the storage class of the objects inside to **Glacier** manually or by using **Lifecycle rule**?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the old days, Amazon Glacier was only available as a separate product. Frankly, the Glacier service is a pain to use.

Every request has to be submitted as a **Job**, which takes a long time to return. Even obtaining a list of archives is slow, let alone restoring a file from the archive.

The best way to use the Amazon Glacier service is with a **third-party tool** (eg Cloudberry Backup) that knows how to interface with Glacier, isolating you from having to use it directly.

Then, [in 2012](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/archive-s3-to-glacier/), the Amazon S3 team introduced a new **Glacier Storage Class** where S3 would move the data to Glacier, but still present the objects as being "in S3". (Well, the objects *appear* in S3 and their metadata is accessible, but the *contents* of the objects is stored in Glacier.) Then, [in 2019](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-s3-storage-class-glacier-deep-archive/), an even lower-cost **Glacier Deep Archive** storage class offered *even lower prices* than available through Amazon Glacier itself.

Therefore, it is now both **easier and lower cost to use Glacier via Amazon S3 storage classes**.

Amazon Glacier still remains available for use, and has been renamed **Amazon S3 Glacier** to further confuse things. There might be some use-cases where it is preferable to use (eg acting like traditional tape backups for AWS Storage Gateway [Tape Gateways](https://aws.amazon.com/storagegateway/vtl/)), but Glacier Deep Archive in S3 would be the lowest-cost option.

Answer (score 5):

These days most people will just use S3 glacier storage class, because S3 api is much more convenient to work with then Glacier api.

However, Amazon S3 Glacier offers some extra functionality, not available in regular S3. Most notably this would be [Vault Lock Policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/vault-lock-policy.html) which allow  for **fine-grain control** of locking your vaults with archives for regulatory purposes.

S3 offers [Object Lock](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lock-overview.html) which performs similar function, but it is not as versatile as vault lock policies. For example, the s3 object locks can be only enabled on bucket creation,  and legal holds apply only to individual versions of objects. In contrast, vault lock policies, as the names suggest, are policy documents written in json, which don't have such limitations.