# AWS S3 Life Cycle Configuration Move to Glacier and Delete in Bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

I have a question on creating a lifecycle rule for an s3 bucket.

I want to remove all objects in a bucket after one day and move them to Glacier Instant Retrieval.

Is this possible to do?

I had this set up.

{'Rules': [{'ID': 'ID',

'Filter': {},

'Status': 'Enabled',

'Transitions': [{'Days': 1, 'StorageClass': 'GLACIER_IR'},

{'Days': 365, 'StorageClass': 'DEEP_ARCHIVE'}]}]}

But I do not see them in glacier and they are still in the bucket.

Are there an IAM policies I need to set for the s3 bucket or a glacier vault?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean "I do not see them in glacier and they are still in the bucket"?  By changing the storage class, they should still be in the bucket, just with a different storage class.

Comment: I thought it was supposed to move them from the bucket to a vault, I did not realized it changes the storage class. Thank you so much. What are vaults used for then?

Comment: [This question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65917080/amazon-s3-glacier-vs-glacier-storage-class) covers the difference.  The simple version is Glacier Vaults predates S3 storage classes.